# Remove rows based on value in a column in R

Tags: r, row

I would like to remove in the data frame all rows where column **a** = 2, 3 or 7

**df**

```
      a
wt_1  2
wt_2  1
wt_3  7
wt_4  3
wt_5  17
wt_6  33
```

Comment: `subset(df, !a %in% c(2, 3,7))`

Comment: df[which(!df$a %in% c(2,3,7)),]